# How to add text to a data point on gmap C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I am working on a gmap windows form application.
I would like to know how to add text to point on gmap application.
**For example:

I have 2 points (shown in the image below by the red and green balloons).

Above the red balloon I want a text label saying "Arduino 1"

and above the green balloon I want a text label saying "Arduino 2".
How do I do this?**

[image]

Here's the code I have so far:

```
using GMap.NET;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace gmaps_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Initialize map:
            gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.OpenCycleMapProvider.Instance;
            GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
            gmap.Position = new PointLatLng(-36.853427, 174.770385);

            // Set zoom 0 is fine, 18 is country level zoom.
            gmap.MinZoom = 0;
            gmap.MaxZoom = 18;

            GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");
            GMarkerGoogle marker1 = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-36.853427, 174.770385), GMarkerGoogleType.green);
            GMarkerGoogle marker2 = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-36.854427, 174.780385), GMarkerGoogleType.red);
            markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker1);
            markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker2);
            gmap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);

            // Re-index the local cache to load map faster.
            GMaps.Instance.OptimizeMapDb(null);

            gmap.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:
https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMapMarker.cs

All you need to do is add these lines of code:

```
  marker1.ToolTipText = "ARDUINO 1";
  marker2.ToolTipText = "ARDUINO 2";
```

Comment: There is not any variable for marker as ToolTipText available there in Gmap.net

Answer (score 1):

@theQuestionMan was right:

```
marker1.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.Always;
marker1.ToolTipText = "ARDUINO 1";
```